# How to create a new table for relationship between these tables

Tags: t-sql

I have table Work. it's look like

```
CREATE TABLE work
(
work_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
type_of_service_conn int NOT NULL,
period_of_execution int NOT NULL,
mechanic_conn int NOT NULL,
spare_conn int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (mechanic_conn) REFERENCES mechanic(mechanic_id),
FOREIGN KEY (type_of_service_conn) REFERENCES type_of_service(type_of_service_id),
FOREIGN KEY (spare_conn) REFERENCES spares(spare_id),
)
```

And i have table Spares

```
CREATE TABLE spares
(
spare_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
name_of_spare nvarchar NOT NULL,
price_for_spare decimal NOT NULL
)
```

For example, for repair of the engine are needed bolts, washers and nuts. How to link these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are probably 1:n relationships.

You need a third table, that stores what kind of parts are used for what repair_id, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE spares_for_work (
    work_id INT NOT NULL,
    spare_id INT NOT NULL,
    count INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (work_id) REFERENCES work(work_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (spare_id) REFERENCES spares(spare_id) );
```

Then you cant put multiple parts in a work_id. E.g.: you put in `spares_for_work`:

```
work_id = 1, spare_id=12, count=1
work_id = 1, spare_id=16, count=12
...
```

When you then select from `spares_for_work` the `work_id` `1`, you will get all spares needed for that work.

Comment: can you help me once more?

Comment: With what? You need to ask a question :)